# How to set the controller's name in MVC attribute routing?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

**Description**

---

I am using *only* Attribute Routing in one of my MVC Controllers:

```
[RoutPrefix("Groups")] // NOTE: I want to use "Groups" with an "s" here.
public class GroupController : Controller 
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Edit/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
    {
        //...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Edit")]
    public ActionResult Edit(GroupEditViewModel model) 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the Razor view, whenever using helpers such as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Edit", new {controller = "Groups", id = "someId"})
```

or

```
@Html.BeginForm(actionName: "Edit", controllerName: "Groups")
{
}
```

The routes generated by the helper function are `null`:

```
<a href>Text</a>
```

and

```
<form action></form>
```

**Question**

---

- Is this happenning because the controller's name is unknown maybe?
- Is there a way I can set the name of the controller with using *Only Attribute Routing* ?

Answer (score 4):

Common practices known for attribute routing are setting `RoutePrefix` with same name as controller's name:

```
[RoutePrefix("Group")]
public class GroupController : Controller 
{
    // ...
}
```

However, as I had seen [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/bhushangawale/attribute-based-routing-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/), custom name(s) can be set without altering/removing original route:

```
[RoutePrefix("Groups")]
public class GroupController : Controller 
{
    // ...
}
```

Remember that `RoutePrefix` attribute only giving alternative way to access corresponding controller, not changing its original name.

> Route Prefixes are nothing but the prefix for any route that we want to apply, all we need to do is to define the route prefix on a controller so that all the action methods inside it can follow the prefix.

OTP, since "Groups" is just a `RoutePrefix` parameter value instead of controller class, all HTML helpers used "Groups" as controller name will return null value on respective HTML attributes.

Thus, original controller's name must be used instead of `RoutePrefix` value:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Edit", new {controller = "Group", id = "someId"})

@Html.BeginForm(actionName: "Edit", controllerName: "Group")
{
}
```

or use `MapRoute` inside `RegisterRoutes` method to manipulate URL together with original controller's name:

```
// note that "Group" controller declared with "Groups" as part of relative URL
routes.MapRoute("Groups", "Groups/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Group", action = "Edit", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

To activate `RoutePrefix` effect when routing, `MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` should inserted into `RegisterRoutes` method.

CMIIW.

Comment: How can this be done using attribute routing in WebAPI 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

The route prefix attribute, `[RoutePrefix("Groups")]`, controls the resulting URL. MVC, however will always use the class name as the name of the controller.

They don't have to be the same.  You can simply use the route prefix to control the resulting URL and use the class name as the controller name where required and the resulting URL will be correct.

In your example:

```
[RoutePrefix("Groups")] 
public class GroupController : Controller 
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Edit/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
    {
        //...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Edit")]
    public ActionResult Edit(GroupEditViewModel model) 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The following

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Edit", new {controller = "Group", id = "someId"})
```

would result in a link that looked like this (note the "Groups" in the URL despite the "Group" controller name):

```
<a href="/Groups/Edit/someId">Text</a>
```